# Two SIMILAR docker-compose files are not giving the same result

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, cypress

This is my `Dockerfile` in `./`:

```
FROM cypress/base:10
COPY package.json package.json
# to install all the necessary packages from packages.json
RUN npm i
# copy in the tests, fixtures, plugins and any custom commands
COPY ./cypress ./cypress
COPY ./cypress.json ./cypress.json
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress run
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file in which the tests have no problem in visiting `pa-portal:8080`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  pa-portal:
    image: company-docker-registry.company.net/project/web_page:latest
    container_name: pa-portal
    volumes:
      - productDB:/project_webpage/db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  cypress:
    image: "cypress/included:4.4.0"
    depends_on:
      - pa-portal
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://pa-portal:8080
    working_dir: /cypress-testing

    volumes:
      - ./:/cypress-testing

volumes:
  productDB:
```

However I realised I needed my own dependencies (and hence why I created my own Dockerfile), but I didn't change anything in the "pa-portal" service, yet my tests say "failed trying to load http://pa-portal:8080", using the following file which I have named `docker-compose copy.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  pa-portal:
    image: company-docker-registry.company.net/project/web_page:latest
    container_name: pa-portal
    volumes:
      - productDB:/project_webpage/db

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  cypress:
    build: ./
    depends_on:
      - pa-portal
    volumes:
      - productDB:/db

volumes:
    productDB:
```

Comment: Is the old container still running or it's not removed even if it's stopped? Does `docker container ls -a` show that there's a container for the `pa-portal` service?

Comment: @MarkoE `docker container ls -a` doesn't show any containers, I even did a system prune